# Get access to value

Tags: c#

I have a method to call service and return a response object. I need some of data in response object. I can get access to them by having dot after response like:

```
  CVAResponse response = new CVAResponse();
              response = dataExchange.AddOrder(Username, Password, order);
              OrderId= response.Data;
```

There are some fields in response object that I need their value and they are not accessible using (response dot) and they are not in root of response too when I look at the response object during debug. They are inside this name space and base like:

- BookClassLibrary.DataService.CVAOrderResponse

  -base

How I can access to that? (I tried dot after response object but there is not such a this thing)

The CVAResponse class is written by another company and when I go to the definition that is only thing I see:

```
  public partial class CVAResponse : object,System.Runtime.Serialization.IExtensibleDataObject, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {

    [System.NonSerializedAttribute()]
    private System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject extensionDataField;

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.OptionalFieldAttribute()]
    private string DataField;

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.OptionalFieldAttribute()]
    private string ErrorMessageField;

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.OptionalFieldAttribute()]
    private BlueBookClassLibrary.DataExchangeService.eCVAResponseStatus StatusField;

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.OptionalFieldAttribute()]
    private string TicketIdField;

    [global::System.ComponentModel.BrowsableAttribute(false)]
    public System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject ExtensionData {
        get {
            return this.extensionDataField;
        }
        set {
            this.extensionDataField = value;
        }
    }
```

Also I have this partial class:

```
      public partial class CVAOrderResponse : BlueBookClassLibrary.DataExchangeService.CVAResponse {

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.OptionalFieldAttribute()]
    private string XMLDataField;

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
    public string XMLData {
        get {
            return this.XMLDataField;
        }
        set {
            if ((object.ReferenceEquals(this.XMLDataField, value) != true)) {
                this.XMLDataField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("XMLData");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I need a value of XMLDataField. or XMLData.

It can be solve by using reflection as follows:

```
         var properties = response2.GetType().GetProperties();


            foreach (var property in properties)
            {
                string name = property.Name;
                object value=  property.GetValue(response2, null);
                if (name == "XMLData")
                    xml = value.ToString();

            }
```

This gava me XMLData value.

Comment: It says its a partial class.  Perhaps the definitions you are looking for are located in the *other* partial class that matches this one.

Comment: Oh Thanks, I never noticed that: I have another class to my question that might help.

Comment: Base in debug isn't a method, its showing the base class

Comment: Have you tried response.XMLDataField?Or casting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Reflection (System.Reflection namespace), something like the following (syntax may be slightly off):

```
var prop = response.GetType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
foreach (var prop in props)
{
    prop.GetValue(response, null);
}
```

Or use `GetProperty("Name", <bindings>);` This will get you all non-public properties.  You can try non-public fields using a similar approach with the GetFields method.  However, I don't believe it lets you have access to private fields.